# Erro: “You have an error in your SQL syntax”

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou a obter o seguinte erro ao executar a tentativa de alteração no BD:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CODIGO= 0' at line 1

**O DAO**

```
public void altera(Treino t){
    conectar();
    PreparedStatement alterarTreino = null;

    try {

    String sql = "UPDATE TREINOS "
            + "SET CPF=?, NOME=?, DATANASC=?, FREQUENCIA=?, CLASSIFICACAO=?, MUSCULACAO=?, ESTEIRA_BICICLETA=?, SPINNING=?, ZUMBA=?, ARTESMARCIAIS=?, TREINOFUNCIONAL=?"
            + "WHERE CODIGO= ? ";

    alterarTreino = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    alterarTreino.setString(1, t.getCPF());
    alterarTreino.setString(2, t.getNome());
    alterarTreino.setString(3, t.getDatanasc());
    alterarTreino.setString(4, t.getFrequencia());
    alterarTreino.setString(5, t.getClassificacao());
    alterarTreino.setInt(6, t.getMusculacao());
    alterarTreino.setInt(7, t.getEsteiraEBicicleta());
    alterarTreino.setInt(8, t.getSpinning());
    alterarTreino.setInt(9, t.getZumba());
    alterarTreino.setInt(10, t.getArtesMarciais());
    alterarTreino.setInt(11, t.getTreinoFuncional());
    alterarTreino.setInt(12, t.getTreinoFuncional());



    int r=alterarTreino.executeUpdate();

    if(r > 0){
        **//comando.executeUpdate(sql);**
        System.out.println("Alterado!");
    }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        imprimeErro("Erro ao alterar Treino", e.getMessage());
    }
     finally {
        fechar();}
    }


**O código atualizar**

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                //Recupera da interface Gráfica
                String Nome = txtNome.getText();
                String CPF= txtCPF.getText();
                String Datanasc = txtDatanasc.getText();
                String Codigo = txtCodigo.getText();

                String Freq = (String) Frequencia.getSelectedItem();
                String Classific = (String) Classificacao.getSelectedItem();

                int isMusculacao = Musculacao.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
                int isEsteiraEBicicleta = EsteiraEBicicleta.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
                int isSpinning = Spinning.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
                int isZumba =  Zumba.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;  
                int isArtesMarciais = ArtesMarciais.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
                int isTreinoFuncional =  TreinoFuncional.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;  




            Treino t = new Treino();

            t.setCodigo(Codigo);
            t.setNome(Nome);
            t.setCPF(CPF);
            t.setDatanasc(Datanasc);
            t.setFrequencia(Freq);
            t.setClassificacao(Classific);
            t.setMusculacao(isMusculacao);
            t.setEsteiraEBicicleta(isEsteiraEBicicleta);
            t.setSpinning(isSpinning);
            t.setZumba (isZumba);
            t.setArtesMarciais (isArtesMarciais);
            t.setTreinoFuncional(isTreinoFuncional);



            DaoTreino gravar = new DaoTreino();

            gravar.altera(t);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gravado");


            }
```

**ELE DIZ QUE CÓDIGO ESTA NULO, MAS COLOQUEI PARA ENTRAR VALORES.**
**Bastou comentar a linha em negrito://comando.executeUpdate(sql); e erro resolvido. Isso era um comentário no código que acabou ficando sem as barras.**

Comment: Como o próprio erro diz, você tem um erro em sua sintaxe SQL. O código todo que você postou não tem praticamente utilidade alguma. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o stacktrace, pois aí você (e nós) saberemos exatamente aonde esta sendo gerada essa exeção. De duas uma, ou algum dos seus DAO estão implementados incorretamente ou parametros indevidos estão sendo passados para os DAO.

Comment: Obrigada, vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Onde está o DAO? Esse código ai ajuda menos ainda que o anterior. Adicione a classe que faz a conexao com seu banco mysql, juntamente com as querys.

Comment: Postei o DAO de atualização.

Comment: Letícia, bem-vinda ao [pt.so]! Poste também a DDL da tabela, por favor. Esse erro pode ser causado porque você está usando `setString` para incluir um campo do tipo `DATETIME` ou equivalente.

Comment: Obrigada, já resolvi o erro descomentando uma parte que passou despercebida.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o erro é porque está faltando um espaço antes do *where* e quando concatena fica algo do tipo:

> SET CPF=?, NOME=?, DATANASC=?, FREQUENCIA=?, CLASSIFICACAO=?, MUSCULACAO=?,
>         ESTEIRA_BICICLETA=?, SPINNING=?, ZUMBA=?, ARTESMARCIAIS=?,
>          **TREINOFUNCIONAL=?WHERE** CODIGO= ?